# Getting .xap file of an installed app

Tags: apps

I wanted to get the install file (.xap file) for a certain purpose from an installed app on my phone. My phone is Nokia Lumis 625 running Windows 10.0.14393.693 and is interop-unlocked. Any way to get this done on my phone? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For an interop-unlocked W10M device, the app you want is [App Data Manager](https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-app-data-manage-tool-t3443623), available on the XDA-Developers forum.

Install (sideload) and launch it, go into Apps (may take a while to build the index), select the app you want to extract, and hit "Create archive from installation path". Select the location to save the created file.

Note that you may need to modify the contents of the archive a little bit (and change the extension to .xap or .appx, as appropriate) to get it back into a sideloadable state, if that's what you're going for. If you just want a look at the app's binaries or data files, though, that should be all you need to do.

Comment: It seems that I can't get the archive to a sideloadable state by changing the extension to any of .xap, .appx or .appxbundle. What modification would I need inside the .zip file to make it sideloadable? (While deploying using the wp8.1 sdk application deployment, I get the error of app manifest file missing; this info may help)

Comment: @SagnikPal: Been a long time since I tried that, though I'm sure the instructions are online somewhere. One of the manifest files gets renamed during installation, which is probably causing the error you see; you'll have to in-rename it. You may also need to remove a signature/DRM file, if it's a store app. I recommend comparing the archive contents and layout against a homebrew/dev package and seeing if there's anything obviously missing / extra / different.

Comment: @SagnikPal
Has anybody of you figured out how to re-create a .XAP from an deployed layout or not?
I would need this information as well urgently, since there is no way to install apps from MS Store on WP8