# How to extract XAP or APPXs from apps?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps

Yes. Windows Phone and Windows 10 Mobile is dying, so also the apps are leaving too. That's why I want to know how to get/extract the apps on my phone (even on PCs) to be kept in either XAP or APPXs packages so I still have these copies of my apps that left the platform. I can't get an S8 right now to switch to Android, that's why I'm arming my lifestyle up to maximize the life of my Lumia, and make it livable for me to use as much as possible.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Getting .xap file of an installed app](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/14780/getting-xap-file-of-an-installed-app). The best tool I currently know of for extracting installer bundles from installed apps is App Data Manager, from the XDA-Developers forum.

Comment: How about APPX, do you know anything about that?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to the other question, it should work for appx too.